# Pathname with Regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I would like to know how to use Regex when instantiating a new `Pathname`.

I am instantiating a `Pathname` and passing it to `FileUtils#rm_rf` to delete the file. The problem I am trying to solve is to remove files that have a certain name without regard to extension:

See this contrived example:

```
target = Pathname.new(["#{@app_name}/#{@file_name}"])
FileUtils.rm_rf(target)
```

`@file_name` does not include extensions such as `.rb` or `html.erb`, but I would like to match all files with name equal to `@file_name` no matter what extensions they use.

My initial approach was to use Regex. But how can I use it, or any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Dir.Glob` like this:

```
   Dir.glob("#{@app_name}/#{@file_name}.*").each { |f| File.delete(f) }
```

See more on that at http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Dir.html#method-c-glob